# Ubuntu 22.04 upgrade running apps not always appearing in dock

Tags: gnome, dock, dash-to-dock

This problem is driving me batty. I upgraded from 20.04 to 22.04.  I noticed that when I launch applications, many times the icon doesn't show up in the doc in the running apps section, at least not right away.  Sometimes they never show up.  For instance, I opened up many spreadsheets in LibreOfffice, but no icon appeared in the dock and the main LibreOffice icon in the dock doesn't show the active dots. But after a day of having those open spreadsheets, at some point, the icon showed up in the dock.  Same for the Adobe Reader. I can open up many different PDF files all day and the icon never shows up in the dock.  Sometimes it shows up later after all the documents are closed, like it's a recent application now instead of a running one.  I've completely reset the branch in dconf-editor to the defaults for the dock, even disabled ubuntu dock and installed dash to dock, but it's the same.  It's a pain when I want to switch back and forth between a couple of apps, because I have to keep using the super-tab combo to cycle through the open windows.  If I have an app already as a favorite in the dock, then when it's open, I see the red "active" dot(s) on it when it's running.  It's just apps that aren't already in the dock that are affected.

This is Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS and Gnome 42.4.

I've searched and I can't find anyone describing this exact issue.

Answer (score 2):

Buggy behavior present in Ubuntu for many years, and related to startup notifications. This is a feature where the application notifies the system when it is ready. As long as the application is not yet ready, the cursor will remain the waiting cursor. Also the Gnome notification "Your window is ready" is awaiting a signal from the launched application.

It does not always work well, as you see.

You can turn it off by changing the line `StartupNotify=true` to `StartupNotify=false` in the `.desktop` launcher of the application (or deleting the line - default is `false`.

To do this properly, never edit the original system file. Instead, edit a copy of the launcher, placed in `~/.local/share/applications` if the change is for you only, or in `/usr/local/share/applications` if the change is to affect all users of the system.

The launchers are in `/usr/share/applications` for applications installed using APT, or in `/var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications` for Snap applications.

Thus

1. Find the desktop launcher
2. Copy it to `~/.local/share/applications`
3. Open it with a text editor and change `StartupNotify=true` to `StartupNotify=false`. Save and exit.

Comment: This answer helped me with LibreOffice writer on Ubuntu 22.04 still in July 2023. I did edit the file `/usr/share/applications/libreoffice-writer.desktop` to set `StartupNotify=false` and since then, writer shows again correctly in Ubuntu dock.

Comment: As my answer already indicated, good practice is to change copies instead of changing the `/usr/share/applications/libreoffice-writer.desktop` directly.